# Display multiple records using multiple textboxes using select statement

Tags: sql, vb6

I am trying to retrieve records saved in MS Access database and populate the textboxes with the query result during `FORM_LOAD()`. So far I retrieve one record. But the problem is, when I try adding the same codes, it is retrieving the first saved record.

It is disregarding the where clause in my sql statement. Here's what I wanted my output to be. During `form_load()`, I want to display multiple records (activity description/activity_desc) in multiple textboxes on my form. If there is no record in my database, I just want it to be blank.  [image: Here's my form]

Here's what i want to achive.. 
[image]
Here's my code snippet:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
FrmSchedule.lblnamesched.Caption = FrmInfosheet.Txtname.Text
FrmSchedule.Label36.Caption = FrmInfosheet.cmbsalesgroup.Text
FrmSchedule.lblpositionsched = FrmInfosheet.Txtposition.Text
FrmSchedule.Thisweekdate.Caption = FrmInfosheet.Text3.Text
FrmSchedule.Thisweekdate2.Caption = FrmInfosheet.Text4.Text

FrmSchedule.Label37.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label1.Caption
FrmSchedule.Label38.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label2.Caption
FrmSchedule.Label39.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label21.Caption
FrmSchedule.Label40.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label22.Caption
FrmSchedule.Label41.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label23.Caption
FrmSchedule.Label42.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label37.Caption

FrmSchedule.Label43.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label26.Caption
FrmSchedule.Label44.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label27.Caption
FrmSchedule.Label45.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label28.Caption
FrmSchedule.Label46.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label29.Caption
FrmSchedule.Label47.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label30.Caption
FrmSchedule.Label48.Caption = FrmWeek1WAR.Label38.Caption

Dim conConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlStr As String
Dim clone_rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set conConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

 With conConnection
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
  App.Path & "\" & "WAP.mdb;Mode=Read|Write"

    .Open
End With

With rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
    .ActiveConnection = conConnection
    .Open "war", conConnection, adOpenForwardOnly
End With

'Set clone_rs = rs.Clone

With arsProjects
If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then
    .Requery
    .MoveFirst
    .MoveLast
Else
    sqlStr = "SELECT activity_desc FROM war WHERE time = '8' and activity_date = '" & Label37.Caption & "' and sales_group = 'ALC Holdings CO., INC' and day = 'Monday'"
    Text1.Text = rs.Fields("activity_desc")
    sqlStr = "SELECT activity_desc FROM war WHERE time = '9' and activity_date = '" & Label38.Caption & "' and sales_group = 'ALC Holdings CO., INC' and day = 'Tuesday'"
    Text2.Text = rs.Fields("activity_desc")
End If
End With

Set rs = Nothing
Set conConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I'm doing it wrong, what would be the proper function or code for me to achieve what I wanted. Any help and suggestions would be much appreciated. By The way, I am trying to use multiple select query to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your assigning the SELECT statement to sqlStr but it doesn't look like your using sqlStr anywhere. In rs.Open you have a select statement of "war" and not sqlStr.

Comment: "war" is the name of the table sir @ozziwald

Comment: Exactly. You are querying the whole table. Replace the .Open line with .Open sqlStr, conConnection, adOpenForwardOnly and make sure to move the assignment of sqlStr to before your With statement.

Comment: after doing what you said sir @ooziwald, I am having an error "Object Required" and it is pointing to this part of the code '
        .MoveFirst
        .MoveLast

Comment: Why are you trying to move to different entries if there are none. You should change the if statement to If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then assign text values.

Comment: I just wanted to retrieve records in my database and display it  to the textboxes. Do you have a better approach sir @ozziwald?

Comment: Try what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: It's been a while since I used an ADODB connection. You will need an rs.Next statement after you fill each textbox so it goes to the next record.

Comment: I also tried adding rs.MoveNext the problem I'm having is that when there's no record, I am receiving an error "Requested Operation requires a current record"

Comment: You need those statements in the modified if statement i mentioned so it only reads records if there are records.

Comment: can you give me the exact code on how to do that based on my codes sir? I don't know exactly where to put what.

Comment: Sure. I would be happy to later when I'm not posting from my phone. In the mean time, try messing around to see if you can figure it out.